# Angular+Node app ignores routing and doesn't load View into ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, url-routing

I am developing a Node+Angular application. I am familiar with Angular, but a beginner in Node so I figured it would be a great start. I am not sure if the problem is with Node or with Angular, so I will just post the code here.

My folder hierarchy is:

```
- public
  - AppAngular
    - controllers
        chatController.js
    - models
    - views
        chatView.html
    app.js
index.html
server.js
```

In my **server.js**, I've specified the code below:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

I don't have any API, since the plan is to build a real-time chat with Socket.io, something I've always wanted to try out.

Anyway, my **app.js** looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('ChatApp', ["ngResource"])

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/chatView.html',
                controller: 'chatController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
}])
```

I have referenced everything in my **index.html** like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ChatApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chat</title>

    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/AppAngular/controllers/chatController.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/AppAngular/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no need to post contents of chatView.html and chatController.js since both are straightforward.

Does anyone have the slightest idea to what's the problem? I have a pretty similar config in one of my other projects, with dozens of routes and it works flawlessly but this.

Comment: Hi Mirza, can you please post the error you are getting? Also, please post the entire contents of your server.js. the order in which you serve static files sometimes matters.

Comment: I am not getting an error, the page is simply blank. And you can fine contents of **server.js** [here](http://pastebin.com/wAB6YRNP), as I don't want to make the post any longer... Thank you for answering, anyhow

Comment: I don't see where you are serving your static files on your server.js. let me know if this fixes it for you. http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: It makes sense to add this, I have no idea how it didn't cross my mind. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix my problem. On the other hand, I did get [these four errors](http://pokit.org/get/?8b1d946633d8591ce2ee7fe94d8c87ff.jpg) by adding that line, and each one of those is raised on the first '<' character character in index.html (before DOCTYPE). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh! When I try to get localhost:xxxx/public/AppAngular/app.js, it doesn't return the file to me. Even if I try going on Inspect Element it won't load the content of the script. Could this be a reason why routing's not working? I think so, but have no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: try putting the line I gave you above/below the catch all route. Sometimes the catch all route breaks the static file serving.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference at all.